# ActivityIndicator во время перехода между View

Tags: ios, swift, activity

Есть view c кнопкой по нажатии на которую Segue открывает другую View
Во время выполнения PrepareForSegue в целевой View передается массив с данными

```
    let detailCatItemVC: DetailController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailController
    detailCatItemVC.categorySelectArray =  cleanDetailArray
```

а уже новая View еще производит скачивание и парсинг большого объема данных, и все это время на экране показывается нажатая кнопка первой View, пока не отобразиться вторая View c обработанными данными. Естественно необходимо во все это "завсишее" время показывать кастомный Activity Indicator с текстом.
Есть уже функция показа

```
    progressBarDisplayer("Загрузка", true)
```

и скрытия Activity Indicator

```
    self.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()
```

но все это дело не работает, куда только не пихал метод показа все равно не работает
Код рабочий, заимствованный со [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785715/how-to-display-an-activity-indicator-with-text-on-ios-8-with-swift)
Проблема в том что показать indicator надо во время перехода

Как перекроить приложение  или куда ткнуть строчку показа что бы гарантировано увидеть Activity Indicator ?

Comment: показывайте код. и заодно: если убрать весь код перехода, а просто показать индикатор и ничего больше не делать, то работает?

Comment: да , так работает, код имеет смысл показать только этот  [ссылка](http://uploads.ru/t7Fvc.png)  это вторая View

Comment: попробуйте перекинуть весь код во viewDidAppear. если это не поможет, попробуйте показать индикатор, и через секунду запустить все остальное

Comment: вот подробней. Даже с индикатором, то что нужно (смотри первый ответ)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215462/how-do-i-get-the-keywindow-reference-in-a-swift-app

Comment: во viewDidAppear метод не работает, MBProgressHUD ставить по такому поводу не хочется , метод  UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window не дает никакого эффекта

Answer (score 1):

ставь индикатор на [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].

Можешь воспользоваться чем-то вроде https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: а можно поподробнее про UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window   , а то я порыскал и все не то в гуглах